# create a video out of captured images by combining them programatically in flutter

Tags: flutter, image, dart, video, camera

i am working on a project to capture images in specific intervals, Now i need to combain them to a video file(.mp4) format.

i did researched a bit, but couldn't find proper work around for this.
Need to implement in both ios and android

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.